# How I can delete specific Applicatios/Packages without their dependencies ? Is it possible?

Tags: package-management

I want to delete Akondaitray which comes with K3B installation. How can I do that ? When I try to remove Akondaitray, Synaptic shows it is gonna remove all KDE applications.

Is it really possible to delete specific packages from Ubuntu ?

Comment: I recommend you let apt-get do its work because most of the time when you manually tweak package dependencies, it gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to remove the apps available for download from Unity.

Have a look here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1745118